# redirect the output into a new column in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    wget www.abc.com?id=$i >> sample.txt
    job_id_var=$(grep -E "jobId" sample.txt) # return 5 in first iteration, 10 in second
    run_id=$(grep -E "runid" sample.txt) # return 1001 in first iteration, 1002 in second
done
```

and i want to create a file in the below format
Output:

```
job_id run_id
5 1001  
10 1002
```

Comment: Can you be specific of how you are iterating?

Comment: show the contents of sample.txt or at least the interesting parts

Comment: wget the 10 different pages(via looping), and grep the jobId and runid from the page.

Comment: Ahh!, so please add those in the question, so that, people can answer you better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you -

```
 #!/bin/bash
    echo job_id run_id
    for i in {1..10}
    do
        wget www.abc.com?id=$i > sample.txt
        job_id_var=$(grep -E "jobId" sample.txt) # return 5 in first iteration, 10 in second
        run_id=$(grep -E "runid" sample.txt) # return 1001 in first iteration, 1002 in second
        echo "$job_id_var"  "$run_id" >> outputfile 
    done
```

**Explanation:** 
Using `echo $YOUR_VAR >> filename`, you can append out the variables to files as you want them. I haven't formated this well, may be you could do that.

I also saw you used `>>` to append the sample.txt - I suggest you overwrite using `>`, if it can solve your problem.

Comment: your suggestions make sense, thanks. i have one more doubt what if i grep one more output from a different loop and want to create a new column in the same file with that data.

Comment: One way would be to probably have the output temporarily stored from the 1st loop into an array and in the 2nd loop append to each array element's output of the each iteration of the 2nd loop and write that to the output file.